# authentication login ( DJANGO )

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an error in django authentication with a user model that extends from AbstracBaseUser and its id is a foreign key from another table.

**views.py**

[image]

**ModelsUser**

[image]

**ModelPeople**

```html
from django.db import models

from apps.area.models import Area
from apps.company_dependence.models import CompanyDependence
from apps.position.models import Position

class People(models.Model):
 documentPeople = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
 fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 phone = models.IntegerField()
 address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 codeArea = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 codePosition = models.ForeignKey(Position, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 codeCompaDepen = models.ForeignKey(CompanyDependence, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 def __str__(self):
     return '{}'.format(self.fullname)
```

in the settings I put `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'`

Comment: Please don't post your code
[as an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste any relevant code and use
[code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What is the error?